# Count consecutive cells multiple times in Excel without repeating

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I'd like to have a formula that counts consecutive cells that are either blank or non blank and group them in rows depending upon how many groups there are.

If B1 is blank, B2-B3 have data, and B4-B6 are blank I'd like to output in cells B8 "1", B9 "2", B10 "3"

I can get it to count the first group, but I can't figure out how to get it to ignore the first group and move on to the second.

This gets me the count of the first group:

```
 {=SMALL(IF(B1:B31<>"",ROW(B1:B31)),1)-SMALL(IF(B1:B31="",ROW(B1:B31)),1)}
```

See image for what I am trying to accomplish. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible to get the desired result via VBA. The delimiter cells are modified: on the OP's image, they are colored, on mine they contains the character `-`. It makes it easier to get the last cell with a value/character.

Select the (first) cell where the result will be shown. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBA Editor. Enter the code below:

```vba
Sub Counting()

    Dim i, lRow, actRow, actCol, cnt As Integer

    actCol = ActiveCell.Cells.Column    'Get the active cell column
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, actCol).End(xlUp).Row 'Get the last cell of the active column that has a non blank value
    actRow = lRow + 1   'Set the active cell row
    
    i = 1   'Set the while counter
    cnt = 1 'Set the group counter

    While i <= lRow - 1 'Loop from first cell to last cell with non blank value

        If Cells(i, actCol) = Cells(i + 1, actCol) Then
            cnt = cnt + 1
        Else

            Cells(actRow, actCol) = cnt
            actRow = actRow + 1 'This allows to set the next row that will hold the group count
            cnt = 1 'Reset the counter

        End If

        i = i + 1
    Wend

End Sub
```

Set the cursor inside the code, press <kbd>F5</kbd> or the Run button. You need to run the code manually for each column. You can add a loop to go through the columns automatically.

[image]

Comment: That's pretty great! Would adding a loop be as simple as a "for each col" statement. I'm SUPER weak with VBA. 

Is there a way to make it update every time there's a change?

Answer (score 0):

I played with it and was able to get it to run all columns automatically. I did it by nesting while statements. I'm terrible at VBA so any thoughts on how this could be done better are gladly recieved.

```
 Private Sub Counting()

Dim i, x, lRow, actRow, actCol, lCol, cnt As Integer

lCol = Cells(32, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'This line gets the last column
actCol = 1  'Get the active cell column
lRow = Range("A1:A100").Find(What:="End").Row 'Get the last cell of the active column that has a non blank value
actRow = lRow + 1   'Set the active cell row

x = 1


While x <= lCol
    
    i = 1   'Set the while counter
    cnt = 1 'Set the group counter
    
    While i <= lRow - 1 'Loop from first cell to last cell with non blank value

        If Cells(i, actCol) = Cells(i + 1, actCol) Then
        cnt = cnt + 1
        Else

        Cells(actRow, actCol) = cnt
        actRow = actRow + 1 'This allows to set the next row that will hold the group count
        cnt = 1 'Reset the counter

        End If

        i = i + 1
    Wend
    actRow = lRow + 1
    actCol = actCol + 1
    x = x + 1

Wend

End Sub
```